# Обратный порядок символов строки

Tags: powershell

Бывают ситуации, когда нужно получить зеркальное отражение строки. Допустим, есть у нас `акортс яакен`, как мне привести к нормальному виду? В данный момент использую следующий подход:

```
-join'акортс яакен'[11..0]
```

Но он требует явного указания индекса последнего символа строки. Какие есть альтернативы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнём с того, что можно использовать трюк с автоматической переменной.

```
-join($$='акортс яакен')[$$.length..0]
```

Можно использовать `LINQ`.

```
-join[Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse('акортс яакен')
```

Или регулярные выражения.

```
# так...
-join[regex]::Matches('акортс яакен', '.', 'RightToLeft')
# ...или эдак
[regex]::Replace('акортс яакен', '(?s).(?<=(?:.(?=.*$(?<=((\P{M}\p{C}?\p{M}*)\1?))))*)', '$2')
```

Можно заглянуть в закрома `Basic`.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings]::StrReverse('акортс яакен')
```

Можно еще придумать вариант с указателями, если скорость играет значение, но тогда придётся вынести код в отдельный модуль или записать его в `$PROFILE`, чтобы было удобней пользоваться.